# USB Webcam (Logitech C922 Pro Stream) intermittently fails

Tags: udev, camera

My USB webcam *sometimes* gets identified as a keyboard and - I'm assuming - therefore won't work. A reboot often fixes this, but it's annoying, so I was wondering if there was another way.

> ### EDIT
>
> *I first posted this question based on seeing what looked like strange message from udev, thinking it was udev, but I've learnt (thanks @tecloM) that that's not relevant*

Please say if this is an XY problem - I'm seeing nonsense from udev (webcam device is a keyboard), so I'm assuming it's a udev problem but it may not be. I'm just trying to get the webcam to work reliably! Perhaps udev is just about naming things and that the problem is deeper?

Here's the syslog lines that occur after plugging in the webcam:

```
Apr  8 16:56:21 meowko kernel: [561385.593298] usb 1-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.935896] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=085c, bcdDevice= 0.16
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.935902] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.935905] usb 1-2.1: Product: C922 Pro Stream Webcam
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.935908] usb 1-2.1: SerialNumber: 80ADA8BF
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.937534] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device C922 Pro Stream Webcam (046d:085c)
Apr  8 16:56:23 meowko kernel: [561387.939350] input: C922 Pro Stream Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/input/input230
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 78: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 78 was not an MTP device
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko systemd-udevd[1153237]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device C922 Pro Stream Webcam (/dev/input/event28)
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) C922 Pro Stream Webcam: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam'
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event28 13:92 fd 107 paused 0
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) C922 Pro Stream Webcam: always reports core events
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event28"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) event28 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) event28 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device is a keyboard
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) event28 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device removed
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/input/input230/event28"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "C922 Pro Stream Webcam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 27)
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) event28 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1047636]: (II) event28 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device is a keyboard
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko gnome-shell[1047764]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
...various versions of last line (don't think relevant?)...
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 78: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1"
Apr  8 16:56:24 meowko mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 78 was not an MTP device
```

Running: `udevadm info -ap /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1` gives:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1':
    KERNEL=="1-2.1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x42"
    ATTR{busnum}=="1"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="130"
    ATTR{serial}=="80ADA8BF"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTR{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTR{speed}=="480"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="085c"
    ATTR{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTR{devnum}=="78"
    ATTR{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="046d"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{devpath}=="2.1"
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{product}=="C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0016"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="336"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0288"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="3431"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="68"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="2109"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"


  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0504"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="16"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="32052"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.4.0-66-generic xhci-hcd"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x31"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{device}=="0xa12f"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x06e4"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="133"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I'm on `Linux 5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

Output from `lsinput` (when the camera is working):

```
/dev/input/event27
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x46d
   product : 0x85c
   version : 22
   name    : "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-2/button"
   bits ev : (null) (null)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same Logitech C922 webcam as you have.

I see similar messages in my logs, although they are not all in the systemd journal, as my system is a Debian 10.

These particular messages are created by the X11 display server.

```
[   121.255] (II) config/udev: Adding input device C922 Pro Stream Webcam (/dev/input/event31)
[   121.255] (**) C922 Pro Stream Webcam: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   121.255] (**) C922 Pro Stream Webcam: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   121.255] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam'
[   121.255] (**) C922 Pro Stream Webcam: always reports core events
[   121.255] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event31"
[   121.255] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   121.259] (II) event31 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   121.259] (II) event31 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device is a keyboard
[   121.259] (II) event31 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device removed
[   121.293] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.2/1-4.4.2:1.0/input/input40/event31"
[   121.293] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "C922 Pro Stream Webcam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
[   121.293] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   121.293] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fi"
[   121.293] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:menu,ctrl:nocaps"
[   121.297] (II) event31 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   121.297] (II) event31 - C922 Pro Stream Webcam: device is a keyboard
```

Yet my webcam works just fine.

In my case, the device is listed as `/dev/input/event31`. So we can dig a little deeper by using the `lsinput` tool:

```
# lsinput -v -s 31
/dev/input/event31
   id   : 046d:085c, USB, v22
   phys : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4.2/button"
   name : "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
   KEY  : CAMERA
```

How does this compare to a real USB keyboard? Well, my keyboard appears as `/dev/input/event7` and the `lsinput` result from it looks like this:

```
# lsinput -v -s 7
/dev/input/event7
   id   : 04d9:2221, USB, v272
   phys : "usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0"
   name : "USB Keyboard"
   KEY  : [ 143 codes ]
   MSC  : SCAN
   LED  : NUML CAPSL SCROLLL
```

So, the `lsinput` information from a real keyboard indicates it has 143 or so distinct key codes it can send. The webcam "keyboard" has just one, and it's even named `CAMERA`.

It turns out some webcams may have a button or two for various purposes. The `uvcvideo` webcam driver supports these buttons by presenting the webcam *also* as a "keyboard" device, *in addition to* its main webcam functionality. This allows any keyboard event mapping tool to be used to customize the functionality of webcam buttons, instead of requiring custom software for dealing with webcam button(s) specifically.

The Logitech C922 Pro Stream Webcam does not actually seem to have any physical buttons: maybe the hardware inside the webcam would support a button but Logitech has chosen to omit it from this particular model, but have not changed the webcam firmware to indicate that the feature is not actually present.

My old computer had a Logitech QuickCam 9000 which did have a button like that. In Windows, pressing that button did trigger the webcam software to capture a maximum-resolution still image using the camera.

So unless you have further evidence, I would strongly suspect that in your search for clues on your webcam unreliability issue, you may have fixated on a wrong thing because you did not know that webcams can have buttons and the `uvcvideo` presents them to the system as similar to keyboard keys.

Perhaps the USB port your webcam is currently plugged into is not providing enough power or the connector is loose. Have you tried plugging it to another USB port?

If the camera is connected through a bus-powered USB hub, try connecting it either directly to the computer's built-in USB port, or into a hub that has its own power supply (so the hub can provide more power to devices plugged into it).

When the webcam is not working, does unplugging & re-plugging its USB cable fix it? If not, you could try unloading & reloading the `uvcvideo` driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Unloading & reloading the driver forces a full re-initialization of the driver state, in case something has gone wrong within the driver.

If `modprobe -r uvcvideo` fails, then either *something* is using the webcam, or at least some of its functionality, like its microphone, or the communication between the driver and the webcam has already crashed.

Check the  `dmesg` output for errors, and try `fuser /dev/video*` as root to try and identify any process that might be using the video part of the webcam, and `fuser /dev/input/event27` for the input device part.

Unfortunately checking for the use of the audio part is more complicated; does anyone else know a good low-level command for identifying any process using a particular ALSA audio device? (Feel free to edit this answer or add your own if you know.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The camera was attached to a powered hub. I checked today and you're right: there's no difference in the logs between when it's working or not! I installed lsinput from `input-utils` but think it's a different version to yours; I don't see the 'KEY' field and the manpage doesn't list any options. I was unable to `modprobe -r uvcvideo` as it reported it was in use (perhaps by built-in webcam?) though I was not using the cameras at the time.

Comment: I'm tempted to close/delete this question as I think it's possibly too localised/broad, but maybe I should keep it for the sake of your reply that may be helpful to others..

Comment: Please see my edit above.